# How to get the value from a JSON key in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I Creating an IONIC 4 APP, and I have a service that reads a json like this

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "internos": 1,
      "externos": 2,
      "cancelados": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to save these 3 values into separated variables

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadHomeService } from './load-home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  eventosInternos : number // this should receive: 1 
  eventosExternos : number // this should receive: 2 
  eventosCancelados: number // this should receive: 3  

constructor(private homeService: LoadHomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How many objects can there be within `home`? Is it a list of many objects? Or just 1 object?

Comment: Just one with these 3 propertys

Comment: Ok, and you have defined the method that does the API call on your service, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think your ngOninit should be nested within the constructor, as that is not how it works. Assuming that the API call method on your service is called `getData`, you can do something like this:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  eventosInternos : number // this should receive: 1 
  eventosExternos : number // this should receive: 2 
  eventosCancelados: number // this should receive: 3  

  constructor(private homeService: LoadHomeService) { 
    this.loadHomeData();
  }

  loadHomeData() {
    this.homeService.getData().subscribe(response => {
      this.eventosInternos = response['home'][0]['internos];
      this.eventosExternos = response['home'][0]['externos];
      this.eventosCancelados = response['home'][0]['cancelados];

    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding one more thought, **Object Destructuring** will also be suitable here.

```
const yourResponseData = {
    "home": [
        {
            "internos": 1,
            "externos": 2,
            "cancelados": 3
        }
    ]
};

export interface Home {
        internos: number;
        externos: number;
        cancelados: number;
 }

const home: Home[] = yourResponseData.home;
// Object Destructuring
const { internos, externos, cancelados } = <Home>home[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable that will receive the json (I'll call it json_example for demonstration), then you create a variable that will receive the items in the key `home`, but, since it is a list, you use brackets to determinate it's "address" and now the keys you want are accessible.

You'll end with a code similar to this:

```
var variable = (<any>json_example).home[0];

var internos = variable.internos;
var externos = variable.externos;
var cancelados = variable.cancelados;
```